# MySQL selecting from 2 or more tables, with a where clause that has a condition from table A in table B

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I'm trying to do a select from 2 tables. However in table B I need to get a value from table A.

I'm simplifying this for the sake of ease, but the end result is a very complex query, and this is the only part thats causing problems.

In this example we're using 2 tables - one for members, one for the membership they are linked to.

Here's the code:

```
   SELECT member.id member.name, member.email .membership.type, membership.status FROM
    (
        (SELECT * FROM tbl_members) AS member,
        (SELECT * FROM tbl_memberships WHERE tbl_memberships.memberid = member.id) AS membership
    )
```

The problem is that in the second select query, you cant access member.id, so how would you go about accessing information from the first query, in the second query, if this is even possible. If it isn't possible, what are the other options, bearing in mind **a join cant return multiple columns**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But a join **can** return multiple columns:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl_members m
JOIN    tbl_memberships ms
ON      ms.memberid = m.id
```

Comment: In that example it can, however it seems to stop working once you get a second join in there. The problem is that this is just a small part of the query. The end result is a query that spans 8 tables, with joins between them. I had a bunch of joins before and couldnt return info from more than 1 column in each. Not sure if its a mysql limitation or what.

Comment: Also forgot to mention, another limitation we'd hit with the join is the ability to do things such as ordering, limiting, etc - IIRC this isn't possible is it?

Comment: You can join as many tables as you like and sort the result.  If you don't know how, ask a question that includes a code sample and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use left join, if join is not returning all columns from tbl_members

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl_members 
Left JOIN    tbl_memberships 
ON      tbl_memberships.memberid = tbl_members.id
```